# How to set menu bar with child window in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, menubar, childwindow

[image: as the menu bar is coming in the middle]

```
       vbox2.setPadding(new Insets(3));
        vbox2.setSpacing(3);
         vbox2.getChildren().addAll( browser1,browser);

        HBox.setHgrow(vbox2, Priority.ALWAYS);


        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
//        StackPane.setMargin(hbox, new Insets(20));
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(vbox, vbox2);
        root.getChildren().add(hbox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 300); // the stack pane is the root node
        //scene.setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
           MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
             Menu menu = new Menu("Window");
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("browser"));
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("img"));
        menuBar.getMenus().add(menu); 
         menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

        borderPane.setTop(menuBar);
           root.getChildren().add(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show(); 
    }
```

here is the code part where is im adding menu bar with border pane but its hang my application as im not able to login or do anythng  and i had to add child window also  for reference im attaching the image

[image: image after adding borderpane with menu bar]

Comment: Links to images don't work! Have you tried using the fxml approach to style your gui?

Comment: no im not aware of fxml

Comment: and im asking about menu bar first and than child window

Comment: You can create a `BorderPane` and set the `MenuBar` as its `top`, below (as `center`) you can put a view that is always below the `MenuBar` then and switch to another view…
Using fxml for layout is very useful, try the SceneBuilder (http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) for that.

Comment: is there any way without fxml ?

Comment: Yes, there is... Create a BorderPane in Java and set Nodes like a MenuBar as top, center, bottom...

Comment: thanks deHaar by using border pane then menu bar its work thanks a lot how to set child window on the menu bar

Comment: thats work but but doing so my application got hang

Comment: Edit your question and provide the new code that hangs, please... Also describe what the hanging looks like.

Comment: i had updated my question i think the problem is that i have to set the application from parent window to child window over menubar

Comment: Provide the entire code of the class(es) involved please. What you posted is not even a complete method. Admittedly, I don't really understand what you mean by "set the application from parent window to child window over menubar".

Comment: the complete code to access complete code u have to login

Comment: Log in to what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156461/discussion-between-dehaar-and-narendra-kr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic and minimal example of handling views in the center of a `BorderPane` by `MenuItem`s:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            // create the menu bar with a menu and its items
            MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
            Menu mainMenu = new Menu("Window");
            MenuItem browserItem = new MenuItem("browser");
            MenuItem imageItem = new MenuItem("image");
            MenuItem closeItem = new MenuItem("exit");
            // create some different contents for the center of the border pane
            Label imagePlaceHolder = new Label("IMAGE TO BE SHOWN");
            WebView browser = new WebView();
            WebEngine browserEngine = browser.getEngine();

            // set the actions for the different items
            closeItem.setOnAction(action -> {
                System.exit(0);
            });

            imageItem.setOnAction(action -> {
                root.setCenter(imagePlaceHolder);
            });

            browserItem.setOnAction(action -> {
                root.setCenter(browser);
                browserEngine.load("http://www.google.com");
            });

            // add items to the menu, then the menu to the menu bar
            mainMenu.getItems().addAll(closeItem, browserItem, imageItem);
            menuBar.getMenus().add(mainMenu);

            // set the scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            root.setTop(menuBar);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps…

**EDIT**
I just saw your newest edit… In case you really need different windows (scenes or stages), the approach will get more complex. Readers have to get more information about the different windows (like how you create them, handle their contents and more).

Comment: its is correct but difficult to integrate with the complete actions on stage on different different item because its interrelated